# Simply retrieving all records from a store

Tags: javascript, extjs, rows, store

Instead of retrieving a single row of data from my store, how can I modify the following code to retrieve all records?

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyStore');
        store.setProxy({
            type: 'pagingmemory',
            data: store.getAt(0)
          });
        store.load();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `store.getRange()` should work or you can do `store.data.items`. For the `getRange()` call, passing no parameters just defaults to 0 and the last record in the store.

Comment: Throw it in an answer so I can give a an upvote!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `store.getRange()` or you can use `store.data.items`. For the `getRange()` call, passing no parameters just defaults to 0 and the last record in the store.

Comment: Thanks I had a checkColumn and I wanted to make only one checkbox selectable at a time. store.data.items worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is not complete true, since `getRange()` will retrieve all the records from a store first page.

If your store has pages of 50 records per page, then `store.getRange()` will give you only the first 50 records.

Answer (score 1):

This will reload the store with all records:

```
store.load({start:0, limit: store.totalCount, page:1});
```

Take all records from store:

```
var records = store.getRange();`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
store.getRange()
```

will only retrieve the page currently worked on if the grid is not defined to have a buffered store. Store can be set as buffered by:

```
(buffered: true)
```

But that will decrease the performance since the whole page will be buffered even if a single page will be retrieved.

The most efficient way that comes to my mind is:

```
    var pageSize = store.pageSize // will return the page size.
    var totalCount = store.totalCount // This will return total no of items

    for (var i=0; i<(totalCount/pageSize)+1;i++) {
         store.loadPage(i) // this will set the current page of the store to i variable.  
         ....
         ....
    }
```