# Extjs - Get all data on the grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid, when i load data to grid, i paging it with `pageSize: 10`, i want get the data store from that grid for checking the redundant data in other grid, but i just get 10 data because i already set pageSize 10, actualy the data is more than 10.

How do i get all data in the grid already paging?

I already use proxy type "pagingmemory" but not working 
This is my store :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  //extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: settings.namespace + 'model.FormRequestDetailModel',
  remoteSort: true,
  remoteFilter: true,
  autoLoad: false,
  pageSize: 10,
  //proxy: {
  //    type: 'pagingmemory'
  //},
  sorters: [{
    property: 'FormRequestNo',
    direction: 'ASC'
  }]

});
var filters = [];
var filter = {
  property: 'FormRequestID',
  value: data.ID
};
filters.push(filter);
store.filters.clear();
if (filters.length == 0) {
  store.load();
} else {
  store.filter(filters);
}
```

This is the model :

```
//-----------Structure for PurchaseOrder -----------------------//

Ext.define(settings.namespace + 'model.FormRequestDetailModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'ID',
    mapping: 'ID'
  }, {
    name: 'FormRequestID',
    mapping: 'FormRequestID'
  }, {
    name: 'MaterialStockID',
    mapping: 'MaterialStockID'
  }, {
    name: 'MaterialID',
    mapping: 'MaterialID'
  }, {
    name: 'Item',
    mapping: 'Item'
  }, {
    name: 'MaterialNo',
    mapping: 'MaterialNo'
  }, {
    name: 'MaterialDescription',
    mapping: 'MaterialDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'Quantity',
    mapping: 'Quantity'
  }, {
    name: 'UOMID',
    mapping: 'UOMID'
  }, {
    name: 'UOMDescription',
    mapping: 'UOMDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'GLAccountID',
    mapping: 'GLAccountID'
  }, {
    name: 'GLAccountNo',
    mapping: 'GLAccountNo'
  }, {
    name: 'GLAccountDescription',
    mapping: 'GLAccountDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'InternalAgreement',
    mapping: 'InternalAgreement'
  }, {
    name: 'FundReservationNo',
    mapping: 'FundReservationNo'
  }, {
    name: 'AssetNo',
    mapping: 'AssetNo'
  }, {
    name: 'DeliveryDate',
    mapping: 'DeliveryDate'
  }, {
    name: 'Background',
    mapping: 'Background'
  }, {
    name: 'Purpose',
    mapping: 'Purpose'
  }, {
    name: 'UrgencyID',
    mapping: 'UrgencyID'
  }, {
    name: 'UrgencyDescription',
    mapping: 'UrgencyDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'LineStopPotentialID',
    mapping: 'LineStopPotentialID'
  }, {
    name: 'LineStopPotentialDescription',
    mapping: 'LineStopPotentialDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'BackupListID',
    mapping: 'BackupListID'
  }, {
    name: 'BackupListDescription',
    mapping: 'BackupListDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'ReplaceID',
    mapping: 'ReplaceID'
  }, {
    name: 'ReplaceDescription',
    mapping: 'ReplaceDescription'
  }, {
    name: 'FormRequestStatusID',
    mapping: 'FormRequestStatusID'
  }, {
    name: 'IsDrop',
    mapping: 'IsDrop'
  }, {
    name: 'RejectionReasonID',
    mapping: 'RejectionReasonID'
  }, {
    name: 'RejectionReason',
    mapping: 'RejectionReason'
  }, {
    name: 'CreatedTime',
    mapping: 'CreatedTime'
  }, {
    name: 'CreatedBy',
    mapping: 'CreatedBy'
  }, {
    name: 'LastModifiedTime',
    mapping: 'LastModifiedTime'
  }, {
    name: 'LastModifiedBy',
    mapping: 'LastModifiedBy'
  }, {
    name: 'RowStatus',
    mapping: 'RowStatus'
  }, {
    name: 'RejectionReason',
    mapping: 'RejectionReason'
  }, {
    name: 'Approved',
    type: 'boolean',
    defaultValue: false
  }],
  idProperty: 'ID',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: settings.apiUrl + 'FormRequest/GetDetail',
    actionMethods: {
      read: 'POST'
    },
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'data.rows',
      totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    }
  },
  sorters: [{
    property: 'ID',
    direction: 'DESC'
  }]
});
```

Comment: What extjs version are you using?

Comment: Do you want to disable the paging function? (I'm not sure to understand your question)

Comment: No Michel, i dont want to disable the paging. I have a grid, i set the store with paging. Then, when i get data from the grid, i just get 10 from many data, but i want get all data from the grid.
Sorry if my question make you confuse, my english not good T_T

Comment: Do you want to set `pageSize` dynamically according to the length of the store?!! If so... you'd better to disable the paging function. Please edit your question and take all the needed time to ask your question.

Comment: wait wait, if i set pagesize dynamically, does the paging in my grid also change?

Comment: According to [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/infinite-scroll-grid-tuner.html) the `pageSize` can be dynamic. This example could help you... maybe.

Comment: Side note: There is 0 point providing a `mapping` if `mapping` is the same as the `name`. That also means most of your fields can now be declared:
`fields: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', '....']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid view is bound to the store. That means, if your grid is visible, and you load a different dataset into the store, the view will reflect the changes immediately.

This is how I would approach this problem : Create a second store with the same data source, but without paging. Then before loading the unpaged dataset, you apply the filters on the grid to the second store.

Note about the model : you do not need to declare the `mapping` if it is the same than the `name`. Rather declare the `type`, this is important for formatting or if the grid is editable.

Comment: Thanks Meyer for your solution, i create 2nd store without paging. But i want to know, can i get all data on the grid already in paging?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by 'all data on the grid already in paging?  The store and the grid only contain the data of the current page.

Comment: Oh i see, so i just get data in the current page, not the whole data. Thanks for your answer Meyer. Now im using 2 store for get paging data, and all data for comparing with other grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop to change the page when finished until all the values are retrieved.

I think this may resolve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785646/5577577